# How to do perform JSON REST Call with Django

Tags: django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

What is best way to do an outbound HTTP REST request call in Django? I thought the django REST framework would help me with that, but it seems that the framework is more aimed at "restifying" your own data.

Any suggestions/examples are welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: Just use any HTTP library. `requests` is probably the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel says it, use `requests` like in this tutorial: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python